# How can I extract the time from MySQL in the format hh:mm while doing "SELECT *" query?

Tags: mysql, select, time

I understand that I can retrieve the data in hh:mm with a date_format function, but how can I add this to the query when Im doing "SELECT *"?

I have to select everything to pass it as a list, but I also need to have the time only in hours and minutes and not with the seconds.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Someone helped me out and showed me that I can just add the info after a comma. But now I have another issue: I already have a % in the query with a variable, and I think that's what's breaking my code.

```
SELECT *
     , DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%h:%i') AS start_time
     , DATE_FORMAT(end_time, '%h:%i') AS end_time 
  FROM theStores 
 WHERE store_id = %s" % store_id)
```

ValueError: unsupported format character ':' (0x3a) at index 37

Comment: Don't use `*`, list the expressions for each column as you need it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Isn't that something covered by tons of tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple, just use a comma:

```sql
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%k:%i') AS time FROM `table`;
```

Comment: That easy? Damn, ill give it a try, thank you!

Comment: hey @Azamat Abdullaev I get an error when I have other variables in the query. Here is my example

`"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%h:%i') AS start_time, DATE_FORMAT(end_time, '%h:%i') AS end_time FROM theStores WHERE store_id = %s" % store_id)`